# Prove that $|X| = \mathbb{N^\mathbb {N}}$, $X$ is a set of sequences.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$X$ is a set of sequences of elements from a set of natural numbers, $s \in \mathbb{N^N}$, such that in sequence $s$ two identical elements do not appear next to each other (i.e. for any $n$, $s(n)\neq s(n+1)$). Prove, that $|X| = \mathbb{N^\mathbb {N}}$.

I proved $|X| \leq |\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}|$ by stating that since $X$ is a set of $s$, and every $s \in\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} $, then $X \subset \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$.

I got stuck at proving that  $|X| \geq |\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}|$. I know that I have to find an injective function, but I have no idea how to do it. Can you help me, please? And is my proof of $|X| \leq |\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}|$ correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Preliminary :***
*The set of all monotone increasing sequences of natural numbers is uncountable.*

$S$ is the set of all sequences of natural numbers with no two consecutive terms equal. Let $K$ be the set of all monotone increasing sequence of natural numbers. Then $K$ is a subset of $S$. 
Hence $S$ has to be uncountable.

Further if $X$ be the set of all sequences of natural numbers then $S$ is a subset of $X$.

Again $X$ and $K$ have the same cardinality and $= | \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} |$

Thus, $S$ must have the same cardinality.

--Hence Proved--